# Getting All YouTube Video Ids/Urls From Video Manager

Tags: java, html, css, youtube, selenium-webdriver

I'm using [`Selenium`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) to log into my `Google` account and to visit `YouTube`.

Now on the video manager I would like to get all of my video ids. I tried copying the `CSSSelector` or `XPath` which the `developer tools` in `Chrome` give me but each of them contain the video id which makes them impossible to use like this:

```
List<WebElement> allVideoUrls = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("my-selector-which-gives-all-videos-on-page"));
```

Note that I have to be logged in to be able to "see" unlisted or private videos as well so that's required.

So far I have a bad implementation which sometimes fails to work for some reason. I firstly get all the links on the page and only return the ones which are for editing a video. To avoid a [`StaleElementReferenceException`](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) I'm retrieving all links again inside the loop.

```
public void getVideoInformation()
{
    // Visit video manager
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/my_videos?o=U");

    // Wait until video list has loaded
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .cssSelector("#vm-playlist-video-list-ol")));

    // Return all links on page
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    HashSet<String> videoLinks = new HashSet<>();

    for (int linksIndex = 0; linksIndex < allLinks.size(); linksIndex++)
    {
        String link = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(linksIndex)
                .getAttribute("href");
        try
        {
            if (link.contains("edit"))
            {
                System.out.println(link);

                // No duplicates
                videoLinks.add(link);
            }
        } catch (Exception error)
        {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   // ...
}
```

I'm fine with the fact that I need to load every other page as well to get all the videos but please help me to find an efficient/reliable way of getting the video ids.

Comment: `sometimes fails to work for some reason` - could you elaborate? Are you getting any errors? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: No errors. It just stops and doesn't find all links it should find. Probably part of the slow implementation or timing issues. I just need a better approach for this since I get some `NullPointerException`s too when calling `contains()` on a non-existing `href` value hence the exception handling there

Comment: It's probably worth using the API to do something like this. It'd be easier and probably not against their terms of service.